# How can I subtract today's datetime from a list of datetimes to find people's age?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I started with a list of birthdays that look like this: 01/01/1900 and I've named dob. I want to calculate their current age in years by subtracting the current time. So I did the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

parsed_date = [datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y') for x in dob]
now = datetime.now()

age = now - parsed_date
```

parsed_date is a list made up of

```
[datetime.datetime(1984, 11, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1980, 10, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1991, 5, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1982, 8, 28, 0, 0), ... ]
```

Unfortunately for the age I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'list'
```

I don't understand why this error pops up if it looks to me like I'm subtracting two datetimes to get a timedelta. If I do individually

```
now - datetime(1984, 11, 11, 0, 0)
```

then it works, but if I do

```
now - datetime.datetime(1984, 11, 11, 0, 0)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear you're trying to subtract a datetime with a list object, you need to iterate over the datetime objects in the list and subtract the datetime from that entry

Comment: Use a list comprehension to do it like @Patrick's answer. You're getting the `AttributeError` because you've `from datatime import datetime` somewhere so `datetime.datetime(1984, 11, 11, 0, 0)` is trying to access the attribute of a `datetime.datetime` class instance which doesn't have one (unlike the module object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
age = now - parsed_date
```

Use this:

```
ages = [now - date for date in parsed_date]
```

Comment: Follow up question, I want to apply: age_in_yrs = age.days/365 for all the elements of the new list. I tried age_in_yrs = [age.days/365 for x in age] but I get error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'days'